# attributes concatenation with thinking-sphinx V3

Tags: thinking-sphinx

I have a User model.
Each user can speak 2 languages.
So I have 2 integer columns speak_1 and speak_2 in my DB.
Each integer correspond to one language :
1 -> french
2 -> english
etc.

I'd like to filter by facets all the users who speak one particular language (= all the user whith speak_1 or speak_2 attribute set to 1)

So I defined this indice :

```
has [speak_1, speak_2], as: :speak, type: :integer, facet: true
```

I was hoping it will work because this kind of attributes does :

```
has mobilities(:city_id), :as => :mobile_cities_ids
```

But it only consider the speak_1 values in my facets search then
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `:multi => true` to the attribute definition and then run ts:rebuild, does that get things working? Although I would hope TS is smart enough to realise multiple columns means multiple values.

Comment: mmhh after deeper tests I realized that multi: true; is not exactly what I need. It's working fine when I select one single language, but when I select more for example french and english, it sends me as a result Users which speak french OR english, when I need in fact Users which speak french AND english. Of course with 2 columns only, search with more then 2 languages should always send no results. Maybe I should change my database structure...

Comment: `:with_all => {speak: => [...]}` will match both, instead of either.

Comment: I ended changing my database structure because i give me more flexibility (user can now have more than 2 language, and even defined his level.) I have a new model Speak, with language  and level attributes. I defined this index : has good_speaks(:language), as: :good_speak, facet: true and it work perfectly (User  has_many :good_speaks, -> {where(level: [4,5])}, class_name: 'Speak' )